# html css move img to the top line of div

Tags: html, css

```css
.img_small {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="reading_chat_left" align="left">
    <div class="reading_chat_img" style="min-width: 50px; display: inline-block">
      <img class="img_small" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HCjNJDNzw8Y/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="reading_chat_text" style="display:inline-block; width: 60%">
      <div class="reading_chat_left_name">It goes down</div>
      <div class="reading_chat_left_text" style="background-color: orange; padding: 5px">abcd blah In this tutorial I will show you how to create Facebook style chat bubbles using CSS only. CSS Code for Chat Bubbles. Here is how chat</div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="reading_chat_left" align="right">

    <div class="reading_chat_text" style="display:inline-block; width: 60%">
      <div class="reading_chat_left_name">It goes down</div>
      <div class="reading_chat_left_text" style="background-color: orange; padding: 5px">abcd blah In this tutorial I will show you how to create Facebook style chat bubbles using CSS only. CSS Code for Chat Bubbles. Here is how chat</div>

    </div>

    <div class="reading_chat_img" style="min-width: 50px; display: inline-block">
      <img class="img_small" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HCjNJDNzw8Y/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

**QUESTION:**

I want to make it like this:

[image]

In other words, move photo to the top of its div.

Regardless of change of width of window or other, I want to make it sticky aligned to the top line.

Maybe it's so easy or noob question, but need help.

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use vertical-align: 'top' to align the image to the top. Check the working snippet

```css
.img_small {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="reading_chat_left" align="left">
    <div class="reading_chat_img" style="min-width: 50px; display: inline-block;vertical-align:top">
      <img class="img_small" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HCjNJDNzw8Y/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="reading_chat_text" style="display:inline-block; width: 60%">
      <div class="reading_chat_left_name">It goes down</div>
      <div class="reading_chat_left_text" style="background-color: orange; padding: 5px">abcd blah In this tutorial I will show you how to create Facebook style chat bubbles using CSS only. CSS Code for Chat Bubbles. Here is how chat</div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="reading_chat_left" align="right">

    <div class="reading_chat_text" style="display:inline-block; width: 60%">
      <div class="reading_chat_left_name">It goes down</div>
      <div class="reading_chat_left_text" style="background-color: orange; padding: 5px">abcd blah In this tutorial I will show you how to create Facebook style chat bubbles using CSS only. CSS Code for Chat Bubbles. Here is how chat</div>

    </div>

    <div class="reading_chat_img" style="min-width: 50px; display: inline-block;vertical-align:top">
      <img class="img_small" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HCjNJDNzw8Y/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be use this simple trick.

Please add css like:

```
.reading_chat_left .reading_chat_img {
width: calc(50px - 100%);
float: left;
}
```

or give inline css in this class `.reading_chat_text{float: left;}`

Hope this help.

Let me know further clarification.

```css
.img_small {
width: 50px;
height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
max-width: 600px;
}
.reading_chat_left .reading_chat_img {
width: calc(50px - 100%);
float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

  <div class="reading_chat_left" align="left">
    <div class="reading_chat_img" style="min-width: 50px; display: inline-block">
      <img class="img_small" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HCjNJDNzw8Y/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
    <div class="reading_chat_text" style="display:inline-block; width: 60%">
      <div class="reading_chat_left_name">It goes down</div>
      <div class="reading_chat_left_text" style="background-color: orange; padding: 5px">abcd blah In this tutorial I will show you how to create Facebook style chat bubbles using CSS only. CSS Code for Chat Bubbles. Here is how chat</div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="reading_chat_left" align="right">

    <div class="reading_chat_text" style="display:inline-block; width: 60%; 
     float: left;">
      <div class="reading_chat_left_name">It goes down</div>
      <div class="reading_chat_left_text" style="background-color: orange; padding: 5px">abcd blah In this tutorial I will show you how to create Facebook style chat bubbles using CSS only. CSS Code for Chat Bubbles. Here is how chat</div>

    </div>

    <div class="reading_chat_img" style="min-width: 50px; display: inline-block">
      <img class="img_small" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/HCjNJDNzw8Y/maxresdefault.jpg">
    </div>
  </div>
```